# How to create Inventory Receipts from code

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to create Inventory Receipt of 2 step transfer, from screen when we select the Transfer # all the fields will be populated, same way when i tried to pass the transfer number from code no fields are getting populated, blank document is creating, can some one help me on this. please have a look at below code

```
        INReceiptEntry intrgraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<INReceiptEntry>();
        INRegister objRegister = new INRegister();

        objRegister.DocType = INDocType.Receipt;
        objRegister = intrgraph.receipt.Insert(objRegister);           
        intrgraph.Save.Press();
        INRegister objRegisteru = intrgraph.receipt.Current;
        objRegisteru.TransferNbr = "000578";
        objRegisteru = intrgraph.receipt.Update(objRegisteru);
        intrgraph.Save.Press();
```

Answer (score 1):

This example creates a transfer document with detail line and allocation. You can substitute the `Transfer` part with `Receipt`, it uses nearly identical patterns:

```
INTransferEntry transferEntry = PXGraph.CreateInstance<INTransferEntry>();

// Document Header
INRegister register = transferEntry.CurrentDocument.Insert();
register.DocType = INDocType.Transfer;
register.SiteID = [???];
register.ToSiteID = [???];
register.BranchID = Accessinfo.BranchID;
register.TranDesc = "Description";
register.TotalQty = 1M;

// Transactions Detail line
INTran inTran = new INTran();
inTran.DocType = INDocType.Transfer;
inTran.RefNbr = register.RefNbr;
inTran = transferEntry.transactions.Insert(inTran);

inTran.BranchID = Accessinfo.BranchID;
inTran.LocationID = [???];
inTran.ToLocationID = [???];
inTran.InventoryID = inventoryItem.InventoryID;
inTran.TranDesc = inventoryItem.Descr;
inTran.TranType = INTranType.Transfer;
inTran.UOM = inventoryItem.BaseUnit;
inTran.Qty = 1M;

// Lot/Serial number allocations            
INTranSplit tranSplit = transferEntry.splits.Insert();
tranSplit.Qty = 1M;
tranSplit.LocationID = [???];
tranSplit.LotSerialNbr = [???];
tranSplit.UOM = inventoryItem.BaseUnit;
transferEntry.splits.Update(tranSplit);

transferEntry.Actions.PressSave();
```

To populate the details lines of the `Receipt` from the `Transfer` you need to invoke the event handler of `INRegister.TransferNbr` field. This can be done with `SetValueExt` method which raises `FieldUpdated` events:

```
graphINReceiptEntry.transactions.Cache.SetValueExt<INRegister.transferNbr>(register, transferNbr)
```

When setting the `TransferNbr` with `SetValueExt` it  will invoke the `INRegister_TransferNbr_FieldUpdated` event handler of `INReceiptEntry` graph which insert the details lines from the transfer in the receipt.

Comment: thanks for info, am able to create Transfer document as type two-step transfer, but how can i use the transfer number in Inventory Receipts screen to complete the process and receive it in desired location.

Comment: Oh I see, I missed the part you had trouble with. You need to populate the INRegister.TransferNbr field with the SetValueExt method which raises the events. Some event handler is executed when TransferNbr is filled with SetValueExt and will insert the detail lines. graphINReceiptEntry.transactions.Cache.SetValueExt<INRegister.transferNbr>(register, transferNbr)

Comment: The method which does that job is INRegister_TransferNbr_FieldUpdated. I will put it in my answer.

Comment: Hello, i tried like below but it is not working as expected, can you please help me out .
INReceiptEntry intrgraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<INReceiptEntry>();
            INRegister objRegister = new INRegister();

            objRegister.DocType = INDocType.Receipt;

            intrgraph.receipt.Cache.SetValueExt<INRegister.transferNbr>(objRegister, "12468");

            objRegister = intrgraph.receipt.Insert(objRegister);
            intrgraph.Save.Press();

Comment: In your example, the SetValueExt call is made before the record is inserted. If you look at my answer you'll notice it inserts the record before assigning fields value. I made that change to your example and it goes further. Instead of a MoveNext error I got an allocation error. Missing allocations because your example is not complete: INReceiptEntry intrgraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<INReceiptEntry>(); INRegister objRegister = intrgraph.CurrentDocument.Insert(); intrgraph.receipt.Cache.SetValueExt<INRegister.transferNbr>(objRegister, "000114"); intrgraph.Save.Press();